# Why is my UPDATE Query not working?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following update query but for some reason it's not working. I think it's something to do with the "id = '".$id."' but I've tried about three different ways and I cannot seem to get it to work. I've written update queries before with no problems but for some reason this one is being a pain. Thanks in advance.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$speaker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['speaker']);
$message = $_POST['message'];
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$date = $_POST['date'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$complete = $_POST['complete'];

$title = ucwords(strtolower($title));

if ($complete && ($password == "*****"))
{       

    $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname,$db) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("UPDATE sermons SET speaker = '$speaker', message = '$message', title = '$title', date = '$date', day = '$day' WHERE id = '$id'");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT speaker, message, title, date, day FROM sermons WHERE speaker = '$speaker' AND message = '$message' AND title = '$title' AND date = '$date' AND day = '$day'", $db));

    if ($num_rows == 1)
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Sermon Information Entered Successfully!'); </script>";

    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error! Please Try Again.'); </script>";
}

else if ($complete && ($password != "*****"))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Incorrect Password! Please Try Again.'); </script>";
}
```

Comment: You're looking at the `$_GET` variable for `$id`. Should you be looking at `$_POST`? **Note** You're only escaping some of the user data. The unescaped data leaves you open to an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @MikeW - Even with the escaping, this method leaves the code open to injection.  Unrelated, but should be using prepared statements, and `filter_input_var` and literal casting (aka... `(int)`) to prevent this.  `PDO`, or `mysqli`.

Comment: @DRaulie2003 There is no error in the PHP code. What can be in the $ id variable. This value is passed by GET it?

Comment: @SanuelJackson I'd be interested to know how this is susceptible to SQL Injection if all the variables are properly escaped.

Comment: @MikeW - Here is one of many documents on the subject [http://www.webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt](http://www.webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt)

Comment: @SanuelJackson I'm sure it's a great article. All I see is "Request could not be completed...".

Comment: @MikeW - Thats interesting as I am seeing a whitepaper -- I will copy/paste it to pastebin --- you CAN go there can't you ?  --- [PASTEBIN LINK](http://pastebin.com/xNfC4GQz)

Comment: @MikeW - Perhaps this VERY CLEAR example on HOW to bypass `mysql_real_escape_string` (and the likes), will better clarify why escaping simply is not enough >> http://johnroach.info/2011/02/17/why-mysql_real_escape_string-isnt-enough-to-stop-sql-injection-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

Because of id is Integer so this is correct code try thus :

mysql_query("UPDATE sermons SET speaker = '$speaker', message = '$message', title = '$title', date = '$date', day = '$day' WHERE id =".$id);

I expected it will be works.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer as providing code in comments is difficult to read

Try changing

```
mysql_query("UPDATE sermons SET speaker = '$speaker', message = '$message', title = '$title', date = '$date', day = '$day' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

To

```
mysql_query("UPDATE sermons SET speaker = '$speaker', message = '$message', title = '$title', date = '$date', day = '$day' WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then add the error message to your question please.

Comment: I added the die statement to the end and it didn't throw an error.